# How do I check whether the first character of each string in a list starts with a specific set of characters or not in python?

Tags: python, string, list

`list1` is a list here in python and `i` is some constant like 7(integer).

---

Look at the snippet of code below :-

```
for j in range(i, len(list1)):
  if list1[j][0] == 'Ġ' or '.' or '!' or '?' or ',':
    #do something
```

When I execute the above code only 'Ġ' is considered for checking whether the list1 ith string's first character is 'Ġ' or not and the rest '.','!','?'and ',' are ignored.

---

I also thought of using the **startswith()** fucntion like this :-

```
for j in range(i, len(list1)):
      if list1[j].startswith([Ġ!?.,]):
        #do something
```

But then the above code also wasn't working properly, because I realized that **startswith()** function *doesn't accept regular expression. Also, it accepts only one character* so that implies that I can't add parameters like this :-

```
if list1[j].startswith('Ġ' or '.' or '!' or '?' or ','):
```

Does anybody know of what could be done here? Please help. 
*I want to check whether the first character of the string belongs to any of these character - 'Ġ', '.', '!', '?', ','*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
if list1[j][0] in "Ġ.!?,":
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just wasn't able to solve this issue.